# Where is tigervnc-server package in ubuntu 11?

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, tiger

Where is tigervnc-server package in ubuntu 11? What is instead?

**UPDATE**

tigervnc-server package allows to have system-wide configuration file /etc/sysconfig/vncservers file, where one can associate virtual desktop with user name. All these desktops run with system start even if main system starts without GUI.

Which of Ubuntu packages is equivalent to this?

**UPDATE 2**

SourceFourge page http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/tigervnc/index.php?title=Main_Page of tigervnc does not contain the same as tigervnc-server package of Fedora contains. Specifically I can't find a support for autorunning screens from global config.

This site has a link which is said containing Ubuntu packages, but actually does not contain anything matching: http://winswitch.org/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a specific binary requirement for TigerVNC, you could try one of the other VNC packages. Especially if you don't want to update the packages manually.

Running Aptitude should show you the available packages if you're connected to the Internet on that server.
`aptitude search vnc`

Assuming you're using a recent Ubuntu release, the VNC4Server packages should be fine. Older releases such as 9.10 had a keyboard mapping problem in VNC4Server that caused us no end of issues and required use of TightVNC.

If you wish to update packages manually and/or specifically need TigerVNC for its particular feature set from the TightVNC 4 branch, you should visit the [Project page on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/tigervnc/index.php?title=Main_Page) where a link to Ubuntu packages is provided.

Comment: Looks like vnc4server provides another functionality. I need to have virtual desktops to access them via vnc viewer. I don't wan't to log in with terminal (not always) and activate desktop. Also I want to have exactly the same desktop as if I logged into XWindow locally, while with vnc4server I have something reduced which actually works wrongly in default configurations.

Comment: Well, personally I'd do that with LTSP. We run about 300 workstations that way. The StackExchange sites work on a certain algorithm, so unless the last paragraph doesn't answer the questions you posted, please hit the Accept checkmark. If it doesn't fit, please add more detail to the question so that we can better understand what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry I need either tigervnc-server or equivalent. Are you insist vnc4server is equivalent? If not how can I mark this as answer?

Comment: Actually, the link for tigervnc is in the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: But are you sure there are no predefined packages in Ubuntu package system of such a thing?

Comment: Yes, the <code>aptitude search vnc</code> tells you what VNC packages come with Ubuntu. If you wish to get TigerVNC updating automatically, you can certainly add TigerVNC's repository to your apt configuration. That's a bit beyond the scope of this question though.

Comment: TigerVNC from sourceforge is also just an utility like vnc4server, i.e. to run virtual screen from command line. I need autorun support with /etc/sysconfig/vncservers file, like in package. So the question is STILL NOT ANSWERED.

Answer (score 1):

They link to a list of debian packages on their website, which is a direct link to the repository. Here's how to add the repository for Ubuntu 12.04:

```
curl https://winswitch.org/gpg.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo deb http://winswitch.org/dists precise main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winswitch.list
```

Then, `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install tigervnc-server`

For earlier or later Ubuntu versions, change `precise` accordingly